# How to get the exact output "math error"?

Tags: c

Actually i am trying to get exact output "math error"when i run the program i can't exactly finf what i am actually looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int
main ()
{
   int a,b,c,d,m,n;
   float x1,x2;
   
   printf("enter value of integer :");
   scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&m,&n);
   
   
   
   x1=(m*d-b*n)/(a*d-c-d);
   x2=(n*a-m*c)/(a*d-c*d);
   
   if(a*d-c*d==0)
   {
   printf("Math error");
   }
   
   
   else
   {
       printf("value of x1=%f\n",x1);
       printf("value of x2=%f\n",x2);
   }
   
   return 0;
   
   
}
```

Comment: You are looking for input that makes `a*d-c*d==0`, so then... just run the program and give it that input...? It's unclear what you're trying to do and what trouble you're having.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what input you use and what output you get and what output you expect. There might be a typo in `x1=(m*d-b*n)/(a*d-c-d);`. Do you mean `x1=(m*d-b*n)/(a*d-c*d);`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're checking whether `a*d-c*d==0` after you've used it as the denominator in the expressions to calculate `x1` and `x2`. If that division causes a runtime divide-by-zero error the program might be crashing with other error output before it ever gets to your check.

To avoid that, you can put your `if` block above the lines where `x1` and `x2` are calculated. You should also end the program in the event of the error since further computation is invalid in that case. Of course, you need to keep the code in the `else` block below the lines that compute `x1` and `x2`; you can just get rid of the `else` since at this point you know for sure the computation is valid.

Note: choosing d and c = 0 guarantees that your denominators will be zero (the denominators are actually different, I assume this is a typo, but c=0 and d=0 makes them both zero anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division `(n*a-m*c)/(a*d-c*d)` before the check `a*d-c*d==0`, so you cannot avoid division by zero to get "Math error" printed.

Also what is in the `printf` is "Math error" with large M, not expected "math error" with small m.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int
main ()
{
   int a,b,c,d,m,n;
   float x1,x2;
   
   printf("enter value of integer :");
   if(scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&m,&n)!=6)
   {
       printf("input error");
   }
   
   
   
   else
   if(a*d-c*d==0)
   {
       printf("math error");
   }
   
   
   else
   {
       x1=(m*d-b*n)/(float)(a*d-c*d);
       x2=(n*a-m*c)/(float)(a*d-c*d);
       printf("value of x1=%f\n",x1);
       printf("value of x2=%f\n",x2);
   }
   
   return 0;
   
   
}
```

What I fixed:

- Added checking if the input is successful.
- Moved the divisions after the check `a*d-c*d==0`.
- Fixed the message "math error".
- Changed `a*d-c-d` to `a*d-c*d` because I think it is what you want.
- Added casting to `float` to avoid truncations which you may not like.

Comment: I suggest to use braces around the second if/else and indentation in the else branch to make the program more clear.